# Bind with jstree on expand and on collapse events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am facing difficulty to bind jstree with an on-expand/on-collapse event. I am currently binding the jstree with selected_node event like this :

```
$(function () {
$("#tree").jstree({ 
"json_data" : {
    "data" : [
        { 
            data : "/", 
            attr : { "id" : "root"},
            state : "closed",
            "children" : [ { "data" : "child1",
                            "attr" : { "id" : "child1.id" },
                            "children" : [ ] }
                         ]
        },
    ]
},
"plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "crrm", "ui" ]
})
.bind("select_node.jstree",function(event, data) { . . . }
```

I am now looking for the same event handling functionality within {...} for on-expand/on-collapse event as well. Need help to figure out how can that be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.on('open_node.jstree', ....);
```

and

```
.on('close_node.jstree', ....);
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I use something like you suggested as : 
    $("#tree").on('open_node.jstree', function(event, data){
  alert(data.rslt.obj.attr('id'));
         }, true); 
I get the following error :
TypeError: i.handler.apply is not a function. 
Any comments ??

Comment: Depends what you're trying to get. I think you just want $(this).attr('id');

Comment: I was trying to bind with on-expand and on-collapse event on a node. Found the way .bind('open_node.jstree close_node.jstree', ....); Thanks. By any chance you know how can I remove triangle icon (for expansion/collapse) for just the root node ?

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works for you. I suggest you second question be posed separately so as not to cloud this one and make it more easily found by others.

Comment: Could you please provide a more detailed example please? Let's say on open alert the id of the opened node.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want more information about node (like id):

```
$("#jstree").on("open_node.jstree", function (e, data) { alert("Open node_id: " + data.node.id); });
$("#jstree").on("close_node.jstree", function (e, data) { alert("Close node_id: " + data.node.id); });
```